# Register vs Auto Storage class?

Tags: c, storage-class-specifier

right now im learning about storage classes [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xe7xLSBlMV4&index=73&list=PLfVsf4Bjg79CZ5kHTiQHcm-l2q8j06ofd). And he seems to explain the same thing for the auto storage class and the register storage class. The only thing he diffrenciated between the two is that the register storage class is stored in CPU Register.. Are there any diffrences between these storage classes? Any uses of the register storage class? Is Register keyword thier by default on some C Compilers?

```
register int x = 5;
auto int y = 3;
```

Comment: Block-scope objects are `auto` by default, so the specifier is entirely useless. `register` only matters on lobotomized compilers.

Comment: And why does it matter only on lobotomized compilers? And what does that even mean? @EOF

Comment: If you use a modern compiler like `gcc`, `icc` or `clang` and enable even modest optimization settings, the compiler will assign objects that do not have their address taken (or the address doesn't escape the function) to be kept in cpu-registers regardless of whether you declared them as `register`.

Comment: register forbids address or reference operator so may preserve more opportunities for optimization.

Comment: @tim18: It doesn't forbid reference operators in C -- or rather, C itself does so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `register` storage class does not imply that the object will be stored in a register. The standard says:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class
>   specifier **`register`** suggests that access to the object be as fast
>   as possible. The extent to which such suggestions are effective is
>   implementation-defined.

(The quotation is from the [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft of the ISO C standard, section 6.7.1 paragraph 6.)

Storing the object in a CPU register rather than in memory is one way to accomplish that, but not the only one.

Modern compilers (at least according to the common wisdom) are probably better than you are at deciding which variables should be stored in registers for speed, so using the `register` keyword probably won't do anything other than interfere with the compiler's optimization.

`register` also makes it illegal to take the address of the object (even if it's stored in memory).

It's basically a holdover from early compilers (1970s) that didn't perform the sophisticated optimizations modern compilers do. For such a compiler `register` could significantly improve performance.

(Modern compilers, I believe, start by assuming that all variables can be allocated in registers, and "spill" them to memory only when necessary, either because the variable's address is needed or because there aren't enough registers available.)

Comment: First off.. Did we meet? Are you the person in the Assembly chat room? Second off.... Hmm, i have heard the last comment somewhere i somehow forgot sorry.  Thanks a lot for your anwser :)

Comment: @Dsafds: No, I'm not in the Assembly chat room (not sure what that is). And you're welcome.

Comment: One quick question Keith, why would we even use the auto keyword? dosent it jsut default to it? And ughh sorry i thought we met, someones avatar is the same as yours or looks very alike i guess.

Comment: In C, there is no reason to use the `auto` keyword. It's another holdover. In very old versions of C, variables were implicitly of type `int` if you didn't specify a type, so `auto n;` was equivalent to `int n;` within a function. Since at least 1989, you have to specify the type. (C++ has removed the old meaning of `auto` and created a new one; `auto var = expr;` sets the type of `var` to the type of the expression, which turns out to be more useful in C++ than in C.)

Comment: @Dsafds: You would very rarely see the `auto` keyword in C code, if ever, since like you say it's the default storage class.  But it's also very rare for WG14 (the ISO committee responsible for the C language standard) to remove anything from the language for fear of breaking code, no matter how old or crufty. `gets()` is pretty much the only example of a feature being removed from the language, even though doing so had the potential to break a lot of code - it was that pathological.

Comment: Hmm yea while ive done C++ before C, i have learned that in C++ the auto keyword is basically so it can be of variable any type when it gets declared as so `auto x;`. but if it gets initalized it will be the type its initalized as so: `auto x = 3; //x is now of type int`; I was thinking C Had the same purpose as this, but guess not. (Yet another reason why people shouldnt use the word 'C/C++' C is not C++!!!!)

Comment: @Dsafds: `auto x;` is illegal in both C and C++. It doesn't specify a type, and there is no default.

Comment: Oh @KeithThompson so you have to initalize it if it is a auto in C++?

Comment: @JohnBode: Implicit `int` (for functions, not for objects) was removed by C99. BTW, `auto` is the default only within a function definition (i.e., within a block). Outside a function definition, the default storage duration is static -- and the `auto` keyword is illegal. So depending on the context, `auto` is either redundant or forbidden.

Comment: @Dsafds: Yes, that's how it determines the type. In C++ you can write `auto it = container.begin();` and `it` will be of the correct iterator type; you don't have to specify the (possibly quite verbose) name of the iterator type, and you don't have to change the declaration if the type of `container` changes.

Comment: @KeithThompson: as usual, posting before thinking.  I know all this stuff, really.