# why does register storage class take more time to execute as compared to auto

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming. I was reading storage classes and encountered that register storage class takes less time to execute as compared to auto storage class as register storage class stores data in registers whereas auto stores them in memory. But when I executed a code, the results show that auto storage class takes lesser time as compared to register storage class. Can anyone suggest why is that so? Here is my code.
For auto storage class:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    auto int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<=1000;i++)
    {
    j=20;
    k=i+j;
    //printf("the value of k is: %d \n",k);
    }
}
```

this is the result of auto storage class:

```
real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.000s
```

For register storage class:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    register int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<=1000;i++)
    {
    j=20;
    k=i+j;
    //printf("the value of k is: %d \n",k);
    }
}
```

This is the result of register storage class:

```
real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Comment: Check this link and you will find the explanation between the lines. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111073/register-vs-auto-storage-class

Comment: You need to use more than 1000 iterations to get a decent benchmark. It's also possible that the compiler is optimizing the loop away entirely. You should look at the generated code to see what's happening.

Comment: With even minimal optimizations enabled I would expect both of those programs to compile to the exact same assembly.  Probably just a single `xor eax, eax` (or similar for whatever architecture you're targeting) instruction since they have no visible results.

Comment: You're measuring process creation overhead (badly). Also, you may want to learn about measurement error and variance.